# CYGWIN=nodosfilewarning doesn't help cygwin warning

Tags: cygwin, emacs23

When I try to use `ediff-revision` under Emacs 23.2.1 for a CVS-managed file, I receive the following error in the `*ediff-errors*` frame, instead of commencing directly to the ediff results:

```
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: c:/Users/BILL/AppData/Local/Temp/misc.cpp.~1.10~
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/Users/BILL/AppData/Local/Temp/misc.cpp.~1.10~
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
```

My problem is that I have already set that CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning", so I have no idea why I am receiving this error.

In fact, I can verify this right from an inferior shell under the same Emacs instance:

```
> set | grep -i nodos
CYGWIN=nodosfilewarning
```

I am running Cygwin 1.7.9-1 under Windows 7, in case this may be relevant (and I never had this problem before upgrading from Cygwin 1.5 to 1.7).

Any idea how to get rid of this error?

P.S. A subsequent call to `ediff-revision` succeeds without triggering this warning.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The CYGWIN variable is parsed when the first process in a Cygwin process tree is invoked. Hence, setting it in `.bashrc` or something like that is too late. A good place to set it is in the global Windows environment, under Control Panel->System->Advanced->Environment Variables.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, I was exporting that env var in `.bashrc`. Once I moved it to the global Windows environment, everything works exactly as it used to work before I upgraded Cygwin.

Comment: Doling out propers would be, well, proper. Props! This is one of those things that never really *affected me* per se, but annoyed me subconsciously when I saw it.

Answer (score 8):

I added `(setenv "CYGWIN" "nodosfilewarning")` to [setup-cygwin.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/setup-cygwin.el). That seems to take care of the problem without, AFAICT, creating other problems. I also filed Emacs bug #[14541](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=14541) for this.

Answer (score 3):

From within emacs, you may also:

- M-x setenv
- CYGWIN
- nodosfilewarning

as an immediate alternative to altering setup-cygwin.el.